# handle exceptions with attributes

Tags: c#, exception

Can please someone explain, in a very easy/simple way, how to handle an exception via attributes?

For example if I have simple code like this:

```
class Test{
static void Main(string[] args){
    try {
            Console.WriteLine("div= "+ Division(0));
        }
        catch (DivideByZeroException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Attempted divide by zero -->" + e.Message);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();   
    }

    public static int Division(int i){  return 10 / i; }
}
```

How can I change this code using attributes?

Comment: what do you mean by `handle an exception via attributes`?? I'm afraid that you didn't understand what are attributes for.

Comment: I've never heard of using method attributes to handle exceptions.  I can see where it would be handy, if this construct exists.  Though at the same time it would clearly result in a codebase mixed with two different forms of exception handling, making the code that much less readable.  So I doubt the handiness would be worth that trade-off.

Comment: In *Java* you declare the exceptions that a method may throw. This is not a good practice in C# and has been intentionally kept out of the language. So I assume attributes cannot and *should not* catch exceptions on the function or class level or whatever. Better see good practices about exception handling in C#.

Comment: In practice this would be worthless.  How would you specify in the attribute *what to do with the exception you just caught?*  Specify a handler type by method name and type name?  Feh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This cannot be done with .NET out of the box.

tl;dr - There is no "very easy/simple way (...) to handle an exception via attributes"

---

You're trying to handle exceptions in a AOP way (aspect oriented programming), where you *attach* aspects to methods - using attributes, for example.

[PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/) allows you to do this:

Without postsharp:

```
public class OrderFulfillmentService  
{ 
    public void Fulfill( Order order )  
    { 
       try  
       { 
          // Do stuff.   
       }  
       catch ( Exception e ) 
       { 
            if ( ExceptionHandler.Handle(e) ) 
                throw; 
       }  
    }  
}
```

With postsharp:

```
public class OrderFulfillmentService  
{ 
    [HandleException]  
    public void Fulfill( Order order )  
    { 
        // Do stuff. 
    } 
}
```

Beware of the downsides of using AOP though: the code might become less readable (as it isn't written sequentially) and less maintainable.

---

Instead of using attributes, you could also use [Castle Interceptor/DynamicProxy](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Interceptors.ashx)

You will need to create an interceptor that wraps around your object and intercepts calls to it. At runtime, Castle will make this interceptor either extend your concrete class or implement a common interface - this means you'll be able to inject the interceptor into any piece of code that targets the intercepted class. Your code would look something like this:

```
public class Interceptor : IInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
       try{
            invocation.Proceed();
        } catch(Exception ex) {
           //add your "post execution" calls on the invocation's target
        }
    }
}
```

Introduction to AOP with Castle: http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Introduction-to-AOP-With-Castle.ashx